# Connecting to Hotmail's IMAP Server using Telnet

Tags: imap, telnet

Hotmail appears to have two separate IMAP ports:

```
imap-mail.outlook.com 993
```

And:

```
imap-mail.outlook.com 143
```

My guess here is that 143 is unsecured, and 993 is over SSL.  However, when I try to connect over 993:

```
telnet imap-mail.outlook.com 993
```

I just get a blank screen - no acknowledgement or greeting message.  When I try the same thing over 143, I do get a message, but it's encrypted:

[image: ImapLogin]

Subsequently, issuing login commands fail:

```
. LOGIN myaddress@hotmail.co.uk mypassword
```

With:

```
. BAD Command received in Invalid state.
```

I can't even enter this on 993 as I don't get the greeting.

Please could someone advise me as to why this is not correctly connection, and possibly advise as to how to remedy the problem?

Comment: You should go read the RFCs specifying the IMAP standard; they will tell you how the protocol should be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal; it's exactly the same that happens, if you try to telnet HTTPS `443`; the port `993` is for IMAPS, which uses TLS. In TLS connection (from [RFC 5246, 7.4.1.2 Client Hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2)):

> When a client first connects to a server, it is required to send the
> ClientHello as its first message.  The client can also send a
> ClientHello in response to a HelloRequest or on its own initiative in
> order to renegotiate the security parameters in an existing
> connection.

**The server doesn't greet you because you are supposed to greet it first!**

The IMAP port `143` works differently, because it doesn't start the connection with TLS. The connection starts as plain text, and the client request for TLS with ([RFC 3501, 6.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.1)) `STARTTLS`:

> A [TLS] negotiation begins immediately after the `CRLF` at the end of
> the tagged `OK` response from the server.  Once a client issues a
> `STARTTLS` command, it MUST NOT issue further commands until a server
> response is seen and the [TLS] negotiation is complete.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> C: a001 CAPABILITY
> S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED
> S: a001 OK CAPABILITY completed
> C: a002 STARTTLS
> S: a002 OK Begin TLS negotiation now
> <TLS negotiation, further commands are under [TLS] layer>
> C: a003 CAPABILITY
> S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN
> S: a003 OK CAPABILITY completed
> C: a004 LOGIN joe password
> S: a004 OK LOGIN completed
> ```

In other words, both CAN be secure, but `143` isn't necessarily as it's also used for plain IMAP.

---

If you need to **debug connection over TLS**, you cannot use the `telnet` command, originally designed for the telnet protocol, for that. However, there are several other tools, e.g.

- OpenSSL

  ```
   openssl s_client -connect imap-mail.outlook.com:993
   openssl s_client -starttls imap -connect imap-mail.outlook.com:143
  ```
- GnuTLS

  ```
   gnutls-cli imap-mail.outlook.com -p 993
   gnutls-cli imap-mail.outlook.com -s -p 143
  ```
- `ncat` and `socat` (no support for `STARTTLS`)

  ```
   ncat --ssl imap-mail.outlook.com 993
   socat openssl:imap-mail.outlook.com:993 stdio
   socat ssl:imap-mail.outlool.com:993 readline
  ```
- On Debian, `telnet-ssl -z ssl imap-mail.outlook.com 993`

Comment: Thanks for this!  I think you've put me on the right track here - however, when I said the server doesn't acknowledge or greet me, it also doesn't allow text entry.  Similarly, when I issue STARTTLS on 143, it tells me it's starting negotiations, but then loses connection.  Presumably I am, for some reason, unable to establish a secure connection?

Comment: _You_ are, but your _email client_ can. You are just not capable of writing TLS encrypted traffic on your keyboard. Only _Akira Shirase_ a.k.a. [BPS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Programmer_Shirase) has such skills.

Comment: Okay - but to be clear, you're saying that communication over IMAP using telnet is not possible with Hotmail, due to encryption?

Comment: It requires, among other things, calculations that are not very practical to make on paper. Encryption is designed to be programmed.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what encryption is, I suppose what I was asking was more relating to telnet - can it not be given an ssl certificate ?

Comment: With `telnet`, no. But there are alternatives that works as you wish telnet would. Added some to my answer.